# How to call a function with an event handler if the function requires the event to compile

Tags: javascript, jsp, eventhandler

I am currently working on a project where I need to call a script function on an event. This function is called when text is pasted into a textarea. The function copies the pasted text into an array and iterates through the array looking for the code value of Unicode right apostrophe (8217). It then replaces any found right apostrophe's with a single quote. The function works as expected. However I am running this function on 8 different pages and want to clean my code up. I placed the script into a js file that is called on every page in the project so if any more cases it is needed are found it will be easy to implement.

The function is being called with:

```
<script>
    var instructions = document.getElementById("specialInstructions");
    instructions.addEventListener("paste", pasteToPlainText);
</script>
```

The function in the js file is:

```
function pasteToPlainText(event){
    var plainText;
    var replaceList;
    replaceList = new Array();
    
    //converts the pasted text to plain text
    if (event.clipboardData && event.clipboardData.getData){
        
        plainText = event.currentTarget.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    }else if (window.clipboardData){
        
        plainText = event.currentTarget.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    }
    
    for (var index = 0; index < plainText.length; index++){
        
        var rightApostropheCheck = plainText.charCodeAt(index);
        //Unicode for right apostrophe is 8217 (Used in outlook email)
        //Without this conversion a right apostrophe is put on screen.
            // The note is unable to save with a right apostrophe
        if (rightApostropheCheck == 8217){
            // replaces a right apostrophe with a single quote (apostrophe)
            replaceList.push("'");
        }else{
            // pushes all other text to the list that is printed to screen
            replaceList.push(plainText[index]);
        }
    }
    event.preventDefault();

    if (event.clipboardData) {
        
        content = replaceList.join("");
        document.execCommand('insertText', false, content);
        
    }else if (window.clipboardData) {
        
        content = replaceList.join("");
        document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(content);
    }   
}
```

I get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clipboardData')
On the first if statement.

Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Update:
I found a solution. making the event listener with a bind statement makes sure the function is not called on load. That was the problem as the page loaded the function was called without any information. so it had undefined errors and null errors. The correct way to call the function is as follows.

```
<script>
    var terms = document.getElementById("Terms");    
    terms.addEventListener("paste", pasteToPlainText.bind(terms));
</script>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with compiling?

Comment: The error happens as the page is compiling before any calls to this function are made.

Comment: That makes it sound like the error is in your JSP and not the javascript. Javascript is not compiled. However, the error message you showed looks like JS. You should include a minimal reproducible example so we can see how/when the function is called and which html elements are involved.

Comment: It is impossible to recreate this issue if both the call and the function are on the same page. The issue is when the pageTop.jsp is included it brings in a .js file which holds pasteToPlainText.  My main .jsp file includes pageTop.jsp which includes the .js file. On load of the main jsp is when the error is triggered.

Comment: I'm seeing `event.clipboardData` and `event.currentTarget.clipboardData`. Does `clipboardData` exist in *both* the `event` *and* `event.currentTarget`?

Comment: At the time this is compiled event is undefined. When it is called event is a data transfer object that holds the pasted text.

Comment: Javascript can't run until the page has at least started loading. The page can't load until the JSP is compiled, *then* it would send it to the client. Does `clipboardData` exist in *both* the `event` *and* `event.currentTarget`?

Comment: At the time the error occurs no. The function has not been run so event is undefined and does not have clipboarData or currentTarget.